# Vue 3 how to remove item from array with filter method?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I want to delete specific item from array with filter method. This is how I add new items to array first:

```
 addNewInvoiceItem() {
      this.invoiceItemList.push({
        id: Date.now(),
        itemName: "",
        qty: "",
        price: 0,
        total: 0,
      });
    },
```

Template:

```
    <tr
      class="table-items flex"
      v-for="item in invoiceItemList"
      :key="item.id"
    >
      <td class="item-name">
        <input type="text" v-model="item.itemName" />
      </td>
      <td class="qty"><input type="text" v-model="item.qty" /></td>
      <td class="price">
        <input type="text" v-model="item.price" />
      </td>
      <td class="total flex">
        {{ (item.total = item.qty * item.price) }}
      </td>
      <img
        src="@/assets/trash-bin.png"
        alt="Delete icon"
        @click="deleteInvoiceItem(item.id)"
      />
    </tr>
```

And delete method:

```
deleteInvoiceItem(id) {
  this.invoiceItemList = this.invoiceItemList.filter(
    (item) => item.id == !id
  );
},
```

There is second delete method, which is working correctly:

```
deleteInvoiceItem(item) {
  this.invoiceItemList.splice(this.invoiceItemList.indexOf(item), 1);
},
```

But I want to know, why method with filter is not working?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. There was a mistake in this method:

```
deleteInvoiceItem(id) {
  this.invoiceItemList = this.invoiceItemList.filter(
    (item) => item.id == !id
  );
},
```

it should be:

```
(item) => item.id !== id
```